# How do I update/upgrade pip itself from inside my virtual environment?

Tags: python, upgrade, virtualenv, pip, package-managers

I'm able to update pip-managed packages, but how do I update pip itself? According to `pip --version`, I currently have pip 1.1 installed in my virtualenv and I want to update to the latest version.

What's the command for that? Do I need to use distribute or is there a native pip or virtualenv command? I've already tried `pip update` and `pip update pip` with no success.

Comment: @Cairnarvon The package is still named `pip` even if the command is named `pip3`.

Answer (score 1559, accepted):

`pip` is just a [PyPI package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) like any other; you could use it to upgrade itself the same way you would upgrade any package:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

On Windows the [recommended command](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip) is:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Under Windows I had a permissions issue attempting to upgrade pip using pip. Instead I used easy_install to upgrade: `easy_install pip`

Comment: When I did this pip seemed to upgrade (1.1 -> 1.4), but when I do "pip --version" it is still showing the old version 1.1. Tried to deactivate and activate the virtualenv again but it's still showing the old version.

Comment: On Windows probably is better to use command like that: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to avoid running pip.exe from scripts directory.

Comment: Please edit your "dangerous" suggestion; this command may leave user's Windows without any `pip` installed.

Comment: I know it's an old issue, bu to fix the problem faced by Zitrax, I shoud do : easy_install pip and then /usr/local/bin/pip --version to get the version

Comment: @Zitrax, go to the VE folder, find out the Scripts folder, and open cmd there. Then try executing this command. Otherway can be (I am not sure) replacing pip under /VE/Scripts with the global one.

Comment: FWIW, I had to do right click, "Run as administrator" for Command Prompt on Windows to get this to work, otherwise had a permissions error

Comment: Or use the **python -m pip install --upgrade --user pip** which tells Pip to install packages into a special user-specific directory, that, by default, is on your Python module search path.

Comment: For some other problems, once you upgrade pip, but still can't upgrade some other packages, this might help: python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

Comment: I had the same problem as @Zitrax on Windows: the upgrade seemed to work find with `python -m pip install -U pip` but when doing `pip --version` it still showed the old version. I think it comes from a permission problem that prevent to uninstall the old version. I solved it by upgrading virtualenv so that the latest version of pip would be used when creating the environment and created a new environment.

Comment: This command uninstalls old pip, but not installs new version on Windows due to permission error. So this command will leave Windows user's without any pip installed.

Answer (score 118):

The more safe method is to [run pip though a python module](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#upgrading-pip):

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

On windows there seem to be a problem with binaries that try to replace themselves, this method works around that limitation.

Comment: This is now what pip itself recommends, if it detects a newer version of itself.

Comment: I believe the reason this is safer is because on some OSes (Windows), just running pip directly can create a file lock on the executable, which would prevent updating it. By calling Python and telling it to load the module directly, you avoid accessing the executable.

Comment: You have to run the command prompt in administrator mode to get this to work. I tried several other suggestions and nothing worked until I restarted the command prompt window in admin mode, then this command worked perfectly.

Comment: Perfect for multi-version installations of python, where the python executable can be appropriately chosen as `pythonX[.YY]` (`python3`, `python3.10`, `python3.11` etc.)

Answer (score 56):

In my case my pip version was broken so the update by itself would not work.

Fix:

```
(inside virtualenv):easy_install -U pip
```

Comment: Same here, that's the only way that works for me on Debian. Using python or pip to upgrade pip from within the virtualenv would fail because it refused to uninstall existing pip sitting outside the venv.

Comment: Running this shown me a lot of stuff including `Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!` which wasn't displayed when running --upgrade. And it's likely the reason why installing any pip package is failing and why upgrading pip through pip is failing as well, SSL seems broken.

Comment: Lifesaver, thank you.  Tried everything else and only this worked on Windows 10.

Comment: Worked flawlessly on Linux Mint

Answer (score 19):

I tried all of these solutions mentioned above under Debian Jessie. They don't work, because it just takes the latest version compile by the debian package manager which is 1.5.6 which equates to version 6.0.x. Some packages that use pip as prerequisites will not work as a results, such as spaCy (which needs the option --no-cache-dir to function correctly).

So the actual best way to solve these problems is to run **get-pip.py** downloaded using wget, from the website or using curl as follows:

```
 wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O ./get-pip.py
 python ./get-pip.py
 python3 ./get-pip.py
```

This will install the current version which at the time of writing this solution is 9.0.1 which is way beyond what Debian provides.

```
 $ pip --version
 pip 9.0.1 from /home/myhomedir/myvirtualenvdir/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
 $ pip3 --version
 pip 9.0.1 from /home/myhomedir/myvirtualenvdir/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

Comment: helpful for when `pip install --upgrade pip` failed

Comment: If I could upvote this answer a few times I would. This just solved an issue where pip 9.x failed with an SSL error by updating to pip 10.x. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi#29751768

Comment: Well, if you have upvoted it even once I'll be happy. My answers are usually found from an hour or two of hunting and years of experience. Can't say the same for my questions? People can be really mean! :)

Answer (score 15):

for *windows*,

- go to *command prompt*
- and use this command
- `python -m pip install -–upgrade pip`
- Dont forget to restart the editor,to avoid any error
- you can check the version of the `pip` by
- `pip --version`
- if you want to install any particular version of `pip` , for example `version 18.1` then use this command,
- `python -m pip install pip==18.1`

Answer (score 14):

In case you are using venv any update to pip install will result in upgrading the system pip instead of the venv pip. You need to upgrade the pip bootstrapping packages as well.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Comment: after successful install python list still shows older version of the pip. How to point latest version to current environment

Comment: Should I do `$HOME/venv/bin/python3` or just `python3` ?

Comment: if you have activated venv with source /path/to/myvenv/bin/activate, then just use `python3` or even just `python`. if it s not activated run `/path/to/myvenv/bin/python3`

Comment: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip`

Comment: Some distros ship a python3 version without pip. The easiest way is to use ensurepip and bootstrap pip into the same python installation.
`python3-m ensurepip --upgrade`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html

Comment: "In case you are using venv any update to pip install will result in upgrading the system pip instead of the venv pip." - No; you just have to make sure that you use the venv's Python for the command. If you use the venv's `pip` command wrapper, this should be automatic, too (it doesn't work on Windows, but that's because Windows won't allow running executables to replace their own file). Just make sure the venv is activated.

Answer (score 9):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

In UBUNTU 18.04 I got the following error when I execute the above command:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

The below command solves my problem:

```
pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

Answer (score 8):

Upgrading pip using '***pip install --upgrade pip***' does not always work because of the dreaded cert issue: [There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207770/pip-fails-due-to-ssl-cert-tlsv1-0)

I like to use the *one line* command for virtual envs:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python -
```

Or if you want to install it box wide you will need

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python -
```

you can give curl a **-s** flag if you want to silence the output when running in an automation script.

Answer (score 6):

To get this to work for me I had to drill down in the Python directory using the Python command prompt (on WIN10 from VS CODE). In my case it was in my `AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python35-32` directory. From there now I ran the command...

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

This worked and I'm good to go.

Answer (score 2):

For linux

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

For windows:

1. Type Command Prompt in the Windows search box
2. In the Command Prompt, type `cd\`
3. Press Enter, and you’ll see the drive name `C:\>`
4. Locate your Python application path, which is the folder where you originally installed Python

   Here is an example of a Python application path:

   ```
   C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
   ```
5. Once you retrieved the Python application path, type the following command in the Command Prompt:

   `cd` followed by your Python application path

   For our example:

   ```
   C:\>cd C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
   ```
6. Press Enter
7. Type `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and press Enter

Comment: This makes it seem as if the process is much more complicated on Windows than on Linux, but it really isn't.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this worked from the terminal command line in Debian Stable

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Command Prompt with Administrator Permissions, and repeat the command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as some of the existing answers?

Comment: It is but, I was having the issue and it got resolved when I ran CMD with Admin Privileges.

Comment: **Do not escalate privileges to work around an issue**. Do user-level installations instead. The privilege system is there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

pip version 10 has an issue. It will manifest as the error:

```
ubuntu@mymachine-:~/mydir$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

The solution is to be in the venv you want to upgrade and then run:

```
sudo myvenv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
```

rather than just

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation and wanted to update urllib3 package.
What worked for me was:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --ignore-installed urllib3==1.25.3
```

Comment: This is not related to the problem of upgrading Pip itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed Python in `C:\Python\Python36` so I went to the Windows command prompt and typed `cd C:\Python\Python36` to get to the right directory. Then entered the `python -m install --upgrade pip` all good!

Answer (score 0):

On my lap-top with Windows 7 the right way to install latest version of pip is:

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the other answers which say "python -m pip install --upgrade pip".

Answer (score 0):

First, do this:

`sudo apt install python3-pip python-setuptools-doc`

Then, as a non-`root` user (**NEVER, never run `pip*` as root!**):

```
# N.B. bash shell works for this, I have never tested with other shells!
. ....your_virtualenv_folder/bin/activate
pip3 install -U pip
```

Note: `-U` is a synonym for `--upgrade`, as far as I know.

Comment: If you are using a virtualenv anyway, there is no reason to use the system package manager to install Pip in the system Python. When a virtualenv is created, it will automatically bootstrap Pip if the source Python didn't have it. If your distro didn't include Pip with the system Python, that is for your protection; you're meant to let the system package manager manage that Python directly rather than opening it up to any arbitrary package using Pip.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_venv>python.exe -m install --upgrade pip
some_venv>pip -V
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: And maybe you want to apply the formatting skills which your other posts exhibit...

Comment: "No module named install"

Comment: `(venv) PS C:\projects\PycharmProjects\athena-tests> python.exe -m install --upgrade pip
C:\projects\PycharmProjects\athena-tests\venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named install`

This worked for me
`pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score -1):

**Single Line Python Program**
The best way I have found is to write a single line program that downloads and runs the official get-pip script.  See below for the code.

The official docs recommend using curl to download the get-pip script, but since I work on windows and don't have curl installed I prefer using python itself to download and run the script.

Here is the single line program that can be run via the command line using Python 3:

```
python -c "import urllib.request; exec(urllib.request.urlopen('https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py').read())"
```

This line gets the official "get-pip.py" script as per the [installation notes](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and executes the script with the "exec" command.

For Python2 you would replace "urllib.request" with "urllib2":

```
python -c "import urllib2; exec(urllib2.urlopen('https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py').read())"
```

**Precautions**
It's worth noting that running any python script blindly is inherently dangerous.  For this reason, the official instructions recommend downloading the script and inspecting it before running.

That said, many people don't actually inspect the code and just run it.  This one-line program makes that easier.

Comment: The question is about upgrading pip that is already present, not about bootstrapping pip.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem on a raspberry pi.

The problem was that http requires SSL and so I needed to force it to use https to get around this requirement.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple
```

or

```
sudo pip-3.2 --upgrade pip --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

Answer (score -1):

Head to your command prompt and type the following:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score -1):

#### While updating pip in virtual env use full path in python command

Envirnments folder struture

> myenv\scripts\python

`h:\folderName\myenv\scripts\python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score -4):

In **linux**

I will update with this code

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```