# `pip install pandas` gives UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-2.x, digital-ocean

When performing `pip install pandas` on a Digital Ocean 512MB droplet, I get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)`
.

Any ideas what may have caused it? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

[[Full Error]](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7936900)

Comment: What is the *full* traceback?

Comment: @Blender just added to the original post

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your VPS? GCC is being killed by the OS, which probably means that you ran out of RAM while compiling. Either add a swap partition or just install Pandas via apt-get: `sudo apt-get install python-pandas`.

Comment: Yeah, stuff like this has happened in similar situations to [other people](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1880).

Comment: Works after creating the swap partition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like gcc being killed due to insufficient memory (see [@Blender's comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555761/pip-install-pandas-gives-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0#comment30742213_20555761) exposed a bug in pip. It mixes bytestrings and Unicode while logging that leads to:

```
>>> '\n'.join(['bytestring with non-ascii character ☺', u'unicode'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 36: \
   ordinal not in range(128)
```

If it is reproducible with the latest `pip` version; you could [report the bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues?state=open).

Comment: and [to upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15223296/1224255), `pip install --upgrade pip`  (upgrading fixed this for me)

Comment: On ubuntu I could not upgrade pip until I removed the ubuntu package using `apt-get remove python-pip` and then running the above upgrade code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a permissions issue. Did you try:

> $ sudo pip install pandas