# Pycrypto installation failing on Travis CI

Tags: python, pip, travis-ci, pycrypto

I am getting a `UnicodeDecodeError` on my Travis CI build during `pip install pycrypto`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)
```

https://travis-ci.org/ruslanosipov/rblog/builds/21724008.

Any hint where to look for a solution? I can't reproduce this locally.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I've run into similar errors and there are a few possible explanations, including [running out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555761/pip-install-pandas-gives-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0), [missing dependencies](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia/issues/55), or [dirty install environments fixed by using virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1612). This [recently merged patch](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/2012) may be the solution.

Comment: @turtlemonvh I don't think I figured this out, but I may have tried installing pycrypto via `apt-get`. You can give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ruslan. I'm provisioning a CentOS system with multiple python environments in virtualenvs, so that won't work for my case.