# pip installation of gensim - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 53

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install gensim using pip on my Virtual Machine. However, I get the error :

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-jM6uSL-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 53: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I did look for similar issues on SO, and found [`pip install pandas` gives UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555761/pip-install-pandas-gives-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0) to be the closest one. However, I did try updating pip to the latest version.

The pip version details

```
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Any thoughts for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it, turns out it was a memory issue. Here's a nice tutorial about swap memory that can be useful - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473681/pip-install-numpy-throws-an-error-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2)

just

> export LC_ALL=C

solved my problem

Comment: If you are using ansible to install gensim, set the locale in `ansible.cfg`: use `module_lang = en_US.UTF-8` for instance ([documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#module-lang))

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my ubuntu 15.10.
Finally, I solved it by downloading the package from pypi and install it manually by

```
python setup.py install
```

Then I successfully installed it and it worked well now.