# Error installing pandas with pip on mac osx

Tags: python, debugging, pandas, pip

I am having trouble installing the pandas package through pip (and easy_install) on my Mac (10.7.5).

My problem is pretty much this question: [error installing pandas in pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078548/error-installing-pandas-in-pip)

But there is no answer there. The other questions pertaining to installing pandas on pip all appear to encounter different issue (ie no Xcode, or having an outdated version of numpy).

Here's the last little bit of the terminal window:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.5', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py",line 185, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 43: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Typing `python -V` into terminal displays `2.7.6` and I have `numpy 1.8.1` installed.

I would like to avoid installing Anaconda.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does  `echo $LANG` print? is it a utf8 locale (e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`)? Do you see the same issue after setting `LANG` via  `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`?

Comment: `echo $LANG` prints `en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to figure this out.

It was something to do with the version of pip I was using (1.5.5), possibly a bug in that older version.

I installed pandas with no problem at all as soon as pip was upgraded to 6.0.8 with the command:

```
pip install -U pip
```

This thread ended up being helpful as well: [`pip install pandas` gives UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555761/pip-install-pandas-gives-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0)