# Seaborn install error

Tags: python, gcc, pip, decoding, seaborn

I'm trying to install [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) on Ubuntu, and I have all the necessary dependencies already available: Python 2.7, numpy, scipy, matplotlib, and pandas. When I run `pip install seaborn` I get the following error:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-UFktoK-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 43: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've never gotten a decoding error before when installing python packages. Any thoughts on what's going on?

EDIT: full stack trace [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0b5e296d268ffcb929f7).

Comment: Sound like it has encounter non ASCII values like UTF8

Comment: There is nothing to compile when installing seaborn itself, so it is probably failing on one if it's dependencies (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, or pandas). However it is not possible to determine what has happened from the information you have provided.

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like pandas is failing. Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555761/pip-install-pandas-gives-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0 help?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to install Seaborn is, download the package from the github on your local machine. from the terminal/command prompt go to that particular directory and type 
python setup.py install

before you do that make sure you have the setup file in that directory. this worked for me :-)