# Pip freeze for packages installed with --target

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I would like to use for a small Python project this way of managing dependent modules:
http://blog.zoomeranalytics.com/pip-install-t/

In brief, I would do:

`cd myproject`

`pip install --target ./pip-libs --upgrade -r requirements.txt`

then add ./pip-libs to PYTHONPATH and run my script.

This seems but I like to use use pip freeze and it does not allow me to do anything like

`pip freeze --target pip-libs`

to see packages installed in the folder. Of course, I can take a look inside but what is a standard way to show packages installed in a folder with --target? The only way I can think of is doing `ls` of pip-libs and then playing with grep, awk... Does not seem right.

I am not sure if there is a way, maybe it's not a good idea or I should request such functionality for pip.

Python 2.7.9.

Answer (score 18):

Bit late to the party, but I ran in to the same issue and this seemed to solve it.

```
pip freeze --path ./pip-libs > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Not sure when pip started supporting this, but I need to [update my version of pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223296/1093087) before it would work for me.

Answer (score 3):

***Note - this answer was given in 2016, and at the time was correct: the --path argument was added in 2019 in v19-2. So if you have before 19 you should probably upgrade. see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v19-2***

Unfortunatly, you cant do it with `pip freeze`. The docs say that `pip install` installs into that target folder, but its still within your path. So `pip freeze` only shows what packages are installed, not what are installed in a particular place.

You could look at `pip show` which does contain information on *where* they are installed (see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/) but you would have to write some sed/awk or similar to do a grep on the line "Location" and then go back and get the package name.

The other option is to just look at the folders in the install folder and manually work out what the packages where from that... something like:

`ls ./pip-libs | grep -v .dist-info`

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
PYTHONPATH=./pip-libs pip freeze
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pip freeze --path [path location]
```

For current folder:

```
pip freeze --path .
```