# Upgrade pip in virtualenv, when using devpi

Tags: python, pip

(The original title was *Upgrade pip in virtualenv*, but since now I know what the problem is, it makes more sense to rename it to *Upgrade pip in virtualenv, when using devpi*)

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15221473/647991), but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223296/647991) given there does not work. I am running a 2.7 virtualenv. I have just been informed:

> You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.0 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip'
>   command.

Ok, let's do that:

```
» pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./venv2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
» pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /foo/bar/venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Uh? Ok, maybe this:

```
» python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./venv2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
» pip --version
    pip 7.1.2 from /foo/bar/venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

No luck. How can I upgrade `pip` itself?

### EDIT

As suggested by `@J.J.Hakala`:

```
» pip install --upgrade pip==8.0.0
Collecting pip==8.0.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip==8.0.0 (from versions: 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 6.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2)
No matching distribution found for pip==8.0.0
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So it seems that there is indeed a problem with pypi? On the one hand version `8.0.0` is advertised, on the other hand it can not be found ...

For what it's worth, I am using [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/), which up to now has not given me any trouble ...

### EDIT2

Disabling devpi (in `~/.pip/pip.conf`) solves the problem. No idea what the root problem is. I have added [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/devpi/issues/306/not-possible-to-update-pip-itself).

Comment: What if you execute `pip install --upgrade pip==8.0.0`?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala: thanks, but no luck with that. Culprit is `devpi`

Answer (score 0):

use [easy_install](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EasyInstall)

```
easy_install -U pip
```

instead of

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```