# Virtualenv package upgrade and install fails: cannot import name Message

Tags: python, virtualenv

I try to upgrade pip within a virtualenv following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment). The upgrade fails because the system python cannot import the name Message from the email module.

```
(newsfeed)myhost:newsfeed admin$ pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/newsfeed/newsfeed/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip import backwardcompat
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/backwardcompat/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from email import Message as emailmessage
ImportError: cannot import name Message
```

This problem is not just with upgrading pip but with installing anything within the virtualenv. When new package installations are attempted the same error occurs.

In a python terminal outside the virtualenv Message cannot be imported, but inside the virtualenv it can.

Also, in a different virtualenv on the same machine, there is no error installing or upgrading packages.

Why can't this virtualenv upgrade or install packages?

Comment: Is there an email.py file somewhere in the path that could be shadowing the standard library's email module.  If you do `python -c 'import email;print(email.__file__)'` while in the virtualenv, what is the output?

Comment: Thanks. The output of your command is: email/__init__.pyc

Comment: If it were the email package from the standard library I'd expect the path in the output would be in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.  Looks like you have a folder named _email_ in the current directory or elsewhere on the path that contains an __ init __ .py file. Rename/move it and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @snakecharmerb you nailed it. I renamed the directory and it fixed my problem. Add it as an answer and I'll tick it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library's email package is being shadowed (hidden) by a package or module named email(.py) in your path.

Locate the package by calling

`python -c 'import email;print(email.__file__)'`

and rename it or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Your pip is not inside the venv so you will probably not be able to upgrade it like this.

This is caused by the fact that you created a venv that uses system-packages. Remove the venv and recreate it by adding `--no-site-packages` as a parameter.