# Microsoft Azure Django Python setup error Pillow

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service, python-imaging-library

All sorta new to using Microsoft Azure and needed help deploying a Django App to it. When I push the code from my local repo to Azure it gives me this log.

I noticed it says :
 **The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required
 dependency when compiling Pillow from source. Please see the install
 instructions at

 https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html**

I did more reading and learnt that Azure cannot install PIL or Pillow from the environment and hence needs to be installed on my system and then uploaded to Azure. I included a file called ".skipPythonDeployment" so that it doesn't erase the environment set on my local system, but then the deployment would fail again.

The important part of the Log generated while Pushing the code to Azure is attached below.

> Detected requirements.txt.  You can skip Python specific steps with
>   a .skipPythonDeployment file.  Detecting Python runtime from site
>   configuration  Detected python-2.7  Deleting incompatible virtual
>   environment. 
>   ............................................................  Creating
>   python-2.7 virtual environment.
>
> Downloading/unpacking pillow (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) 
>   ....    Running setup.py
>   (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\pillow\setup.py) egg_info for
>   package pillow
>        Single threaded build for windows
>        warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'docs_static'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis*'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
>        warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
>        warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
>        warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
>        warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'docs_static'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis*'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
>        warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
>        warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
>        warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution  Downloading/unpacking Werkzeug (from -r
>   requirements.txt (line 5))  Downloading/unpacking flask-cors (from -r
>   requirements.txt (line 6))    Downloading
>   Flask_Cors-3.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl  Downloading/unpacking
>   Flask>=0.8 (from flask-restful->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) 
>   Downloading/unpacking pytz (from flask-restful->-r requirements.txt
>   (line 1))  Downloading/unpacking six>=1.3.0 (from flask-restful->-r
>   requirements.txt (line 1))    Downloading
>   six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  Downloading/unpacking aniso8601>=0.82
>   (from flask-restful->-r requirements.txt (line 1))    Running setup.py
>   (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\aniso8601\setup.py) egg_info for
>   package aniso8601
>          Downloading/unpacking olefile (from pillow->-r requirements.txt (line 4))    Running setup.py
>   (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\olefile\setup.py) egg_info for
>   package olefile
>          Downloading/unpacking itsdangerous>=0.21 (from Flask>=0.8->flask-restful->-r requirements.txt (line 1))    Running
>   setup.py (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\itsdangerous\setup.py)
>   egg_info for package itsdangerous
>        warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs_build'  Downloading/unpacking Jinja2>=2.4 (from
>   Flask>=0.8->flask-restful->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) 
>   Downloading/unpacking click>=2.0 (from Flask>=0.8->flask-restful->-r
>   requirements.txt (line 1))  Downloading/unpacking python-dateutil
>   (from aniso8601>=0.82->flask-restful->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) 
>   Downloading/unpacking MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from
>   Jinja2>=2.4->Flask>=0.8->flask-restful->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) 
>   Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz    Running setup.py
>   (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\MarkupSafe\setup.py) egg_info for
>   package MarkupSafe
>          Installing collected packages: flask-restful, numpy, pydicom, pillow, Werkzeug, flask-cors, Flask, pytz, six, aniso8601, olefile,
>   itsdangerous, Jinja2, click, python-dateutil, MarkupSafe 
>   .................. : ..................    Running setup.py install
>   for pydicom  .
>          ..    Running setup.py install for pillow
>        Single threaded build for windows 
>        warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'docs_static'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis*'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
>        warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
>        warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
>        warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
>        warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
>        The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
>        a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>        Please see the install instructions at:
>           https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>
> ```
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>    File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\pillow\setup.py", line 756, in <module>
>      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
>  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
>
>  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
>  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>
>  Please see the install instructions at:
>     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>
>
>  Complete output from command D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools,
> ```
>
> tokenize;**file**='D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\pillow\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   d:\local\temp\pip-nu1mtm-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\include\site\python2.7:
>        Single threaded build for windows    running install    running build    running build_py    creating build    creating
>   build\lib.win32-2.7    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying
>   PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying
>   PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying
>   PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying
>   PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying
>   PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying
>   PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying
>   PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying
>   PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying
>   PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\features.py
>   -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\FliImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\FontFile.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\GdImageFile.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\GifImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\GimpGradientFile.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\Image.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageChops.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageCms.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageColor.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageDraw.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageDraw2.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageEnhance.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageFile.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageFilter.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageFont.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageGrab.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageMath.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageMode.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageMorph.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageOps.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImagePalette.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImagePath.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageQt.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageSequence.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageShow.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageStat.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageTk.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageTransform.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImageWin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\JpegPresets.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\MicImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\MspImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\OleFileIO.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PaletteFile.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PcfFontFile.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PngImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PSDraw.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\PyAccess.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\SunImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\TarIO.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\TiffTags.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\WalImageFile.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL_binary.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL_tkinter_finder.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL_util.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    copying PIL__init__.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL    running egg_info    writing requirements to
>   Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt    writing Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
>   writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt    writing
>   dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt    warning:
>   manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
>
> ```
>  reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'    warning: no files found matching
> ```
>
> '*.sh'    no previously-included directories found matching
>   'docs_static'    warning: no previously-included files found matching
>   '.coveragerc'    warning: no previously-included files found matching
>   '.editorconfig'    warning: no previously-included files found
>   matching '.landscape.yaml'    warning: no previously-included files
>   found matching '.travis'    warning: no previously-included files
>   found matching '.travis*'    warning: no previously-included files
>   found matching 'appveyor.yml'    warning: no previously-included files
>   found matching 'build_children.sh'    warning: no previously-included
>   files found matching 'tox.ini'    warning: no previously-included
>   files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution    warning: no
>   previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in
>   distribution    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so'
>   found anywhere in distribution    writing manifest file
>   'Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'    running build_ext
>
> ```
>  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>
>  Please see the install instructions at:
>
> https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\pillow\setup.py", line 756, in <module>
>
>  raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
>
>  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>
>  Please see the install instructions at:
>
> https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>
>
>
>  ----------------------------------------  Cleaning up...  ....................................................  Command
> ```
>
> D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\pillow\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   d:\local\temp\pip-nu1mtm-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\include\site\python2.7 failed with error code
>   1 in D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\pillow  Storing debug log for
>   failure in D:\home\pip\pip.log  An error has occurred during web site
>   deployment.    Error - Changes committed to remote repository but
>   deployment to website failed.

Thank you

Comment: Just upgrade pip `pip install --upgrade pip` http://stackoverflow.com/a/15223296/2625090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you were using Azure Web Apps/App Services for deploying your Django App which contains the `Pillow` package, and the `Pillow` package seems that you declared in the `requirements.txt` like `Pillow>=2.0.0`.

However, unfortunately, there are two issues for using the `Pillow` package on Azure App Services.

1. Pillow includes C code which need to be compiled when deploying your app into Azure. The solution is that you need to build a wheel file of Pillow to add it to your project and declare the wheel file in the `requirements.txt`, please refer to the section [Troubleshooting - Package Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app#troubleshooting---package-installation) of Azure offical tutorial for Django to know it.
2. Pillow as an image library for Python required GDI API & resources. On Azure App Services, any GDI calls are restricted and blocked, please see [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) to know.

So the only way for deploying your Django App is using Azure VM.

Answer (score 2):

Your pip is too old to download the whl (known issues with default version of Python). Please update your Python installation or update pip directly:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/08/04/upgrading-python-on-azure-app-service/