# macOS pip uninstalled cannot understand why pip cannot be reinstalled

Tags: python, pip

I uninstalled pip because of SSH issue. Now I want to reinstall pip. Each time I receive this.

What do I do to correct so that pip can be reinstalled?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
 from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", 
 line 3019, in <module>
 @_call_aside
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", 
line 3003, in _call_aside
 f(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", 
 line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
 working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", 
 line 655, in _build_master
 ws.require(__requires__)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", 
 line 963, in require
 needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", 
line 849, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update pip itself from inside my virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment)

Answer (score 2):

The answer: brew reinstall python

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16432291)

Comment: This is the answer. It installed pip.