# uninstall pip 7.1.2 and reinstall pip 9.0.1

Tags: pip

I have some problems with pip.

So I wanna uninstall pip and reinstall the newest version of it.

But I couldn't find any reference.

So I just downloaded pip 9.0.1 package and wheel.

Please tell me how to do.

I use windows10 and python-3.5 and pip 7.1.2

or...Can you tell me how to download pip.commands.wheel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update pip itself from inside my virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment)

Comment: I visited there, but the problem didn't solve. I just resolve my problem reinstalling python!