# How to install win32com.client on Python 3.4 or Python 2.7

Tags: python, win32com

I tried to install win32com.client using the syntax below, but no success

```
>>> pip install pywin32
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
>>> pypiwin32
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       pypiwin32
>   NameError: name 'pypiwin32' is not defined

```
>>> pip install pypiwin32
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
>>> pip install pypiwin32-220-cp36-none-win32.whl
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 10):

Those errors suggest you are inside a Python environment.  For example, the Python REPL starts with three chevrons, `>>>`.  You don't want this.  Run these commands outside of Python in the system command prompt either through  [Windows](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/7-ways-launch-command-prompt-windows-7-windows-8) or [Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22283/four-ways-to-get-instant-access-to-a-terminal-in-linux/) etc.

The following worked for me on Python 2.7:

```
> pip install pypiwin32
```

Also try the following from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39855328/4531270):

```
> python -m pip install pypiwin32
```

Comment: Thanks, I got error message as below. But I can get on to https://pypi.python.org/pypi from the internet explorer.           C:\Users\n0266997\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>python -m pip instal
l pypiwin32
Collecting pypiwin32
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x032F6390>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pypiwin32/

Comment: That's a better sign that you are actually using pip.  I'd try again a bit later as the connection to pypi via pip can be unrealiable at times.  You may also consider [updating your pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment).  If you are considering Python long-term, I'd strongly suggest installing Python again via [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/?lang=en-us) and creating a new conda environment.

Comment: I tried to update PIP using the command below, still get the connection error. Is there a way I can download win32com.client and manually install it myself?     
C:\Users\n0266997\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>python -m pip instal
l -U pip
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connecti
on broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x032CAF30>, 'Connection to pypi.python.or
g timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/

Comment: I used the commend python -m pip install pypiwin32 on python 2.711. It connects, but gives me error message: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pypiwin32 (from versio
ns: )
No matching distribution found for pypiwin32

Comment: I experienced a similar issue a few days ago, but today I was able to install it in my Python 2 environment.  You may have an odd python installation or pypi is not working well at the moment.  Best advice I have is try again later.

Comment: If you try the Anaconda route in the meantime, it is easy to make a virtualenv via `conda create pywin python=2.7`, then `conda pywin` (`activate pywin` in older versions).  This will be a self-contained virtual environment that protects your root installation from being corrupted by some bad package installation.

Comment: pypiwin32 is more a dummy package than a real package.
It requires the pywin32>=223. This means you must find a pywin32 in pypi, which means there is no need for this package if you already can find a pywin32. And in pypi in the pywin32 there are no wheels for python 3.4

So...

Answer (score 3):

Install the package via command prompt or Terminal of your python IDE(ex: PyCharm)

```
pip install pywin32
```

Answer (score 0):

first command work for me somehow.........

```
C:\Users\AL MARUF>pip install pypiwin32
Collecting pypiwin32
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x032A8C70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pypiwin32/
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/1b/2f292bbd742e369a100c91faa0483172cd91a1a422a6692055ac920946c5/pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/37/917c4020e93e0e854d4cbff1cbdf14ec45a6d1cedf52f8cafdea5b22451a/pywin32-224-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (8.3MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 8.3MB 142kB/s
Installing collected packages: pywin32, pypiwin32
Successfully installed pypiwin32-223 pywin32-224
```