# Unable to install latest version of Django using pip

Tags: django, pip

I am trying to install latest Django version 2.0.1 as mentioned on https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ that this is the latest official release but when I run command `pip install Django==2.0.1` I get error. Error is shown in Image below. How can I install latest version?

[image]

Comment: What version of pip and python?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473

Comment: Python version 2.7.10

Comment: @UmairAamir did you solve the issue?

Comment: Not yet, I am facing another issue while installing latest django version

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Could you close the question?

Comment: are you getting bills if it is still open? I usually don't work in mid of night. When I'll start working again I'll check and if it is resolved I'll close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your python version is too old. From official [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django/2.0.1):

> Django 2.0.1 requires Python: >=3.4

The latest version for python 2.7 is Django 1.11.9.

You can find all available versions and their requirements [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django).