# Virtual environment pip points to older version

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Python 3.5, later 3.6 installed with homebrew and django with virtual environments with pip.

Somehow the normal env shows version 3.6 of Python and 3.5 whithin virtual environment, like this:

```
MacBook-Pro-Frank:~ Frank$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

MacBook-Pro-Frank:~ Frank$ pipenv shell
Spawning environment shell (/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave.
bash-3.2$ . /Users/Frank/.local/share/virtualenvs/Frank-ZvIKOxyS/bin/activate

(Frank-ZvIKOxyS) bash-3.2$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Users/Frank/.local/share/virtualenvs/Frank-ZvIKOxyS/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
(Frank-ZvIKOxyS) bash-3.2$
```

Could someone please tell me how to begin repairing this. Searching for over 30 hours for this..

I'm on a Macbook macOS 10.13.4.

I know it's not a programming question but I would like to start programming and this is a prerequisite..

Comment: It's a programming question — it's a question about programming tools, perfectly legal at SO, nothing to worry about. But what exactly do you want to upgrade? Python or pip?

Comment: I want the same versions of pip in my virtual env as in the normal environment: 9.0.3 that is linked to Python 3.6. Django does not work in my virtual env now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update pip itself from inside my virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Frank-ZvIKOxyS) bash-3.2$ exit
exit
MacBook-Pro-Frank:~ Frank$ pipenv --python 3.6
Virtualenv already exists!
Removing existing virtualenv…
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/local/bin/python3.6m (3.6.5) to create virtualenv…
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.6m
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in /Users/Frank/.local/share/virtualenvs/Frank-ZvIKOxyS/bin/python3.6

Also creating executable in /Users/Frank/.local/share/virtualenvs/Frank-ZvIKOxyS/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Virtualenv location: /Users/Frank/.local/share/virtualenvs/Frank-ZvIKOxyS
```

Testing:

```
MacBook-Pro-Frank:~ Frank$ pipenv shell
Spawning environment shell (/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave.
bash-3.2$ . /Users/Frank/.local/share/virtualenvs/Frank-ZvIKOxyS/bin/activate
Frank-ZvIKOxyS) bash-3.2$ python --version 
Python 3.6.5
(Frank-ZvIKOxyS) bash-3.2$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /Users/Frank/.local/share/virtualenvs/Frank- 
ZvIKOxyS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
(Frank-ZvIKOxyS) bash-3.2$
```

Thanks to [Alberto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5097176/alberto), this solved my puzzle.

Puzzling on...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a specific version of `python` when creating the `virtualenv` you should use the `--python` flag:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/local/lib/python3.6 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

If you are using `pipenv` as this is the case just use:

```
pipenv --python 3.6
```

Comment: Hi thanks very much for your reply. I just want the versions to be the same in the standard situation as in the virtual environment (3.6 for Python /9.0.3 for pip). I use 
pipenv shell as the command to start the virtual environment as you can see.

Comment: I haven't tried it but maybe this helps. From the official documentation of pipenv [https://docs.pipenv.org/basics/#specifying-versions-of-python](https://docs.pipenv.org/basics/#specifying-versions-of-python)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, can you set this answer as correct answer then?

Comment: No, because this is in a comment I can't mark it as best answer, that's why I wrote it out in a new reaction mentioning you as solver. Thanks again.