# How can I update pip3 to its latest version in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I get this error when running

```
pip3 install -U pip
```

Output:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./dlenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (10.0.1)
launchpadlib 1.10.6 requires testresources, which is not installed.
```

I have searched in apt and `testresources` seems to be installed already.

```
apt search testresources
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
python-testresources/bionic,bionic 2.0.0-2 all
  PyUnit extension for managing expensive test fixtures - Python 2.x

python3-testresources/bionic,bionic 2.0.0-2 all
  PyUnit extension for managing expensive test fixtures - Python 3.
```

I've gone through [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5372), which was not clear with a solution.

Comment: duplicate question, please [pip update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment)

Comment: that was pip 1.1 in 2013. this is pip3 in 2018

Comment: it doesn't matter command remains same, which os your using? see bellow,

Comment: have you try?
sudo apt install python3-testresources

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. Wonder why it was not automatically installed as a dependency for pip3. Please add as answer.

Comment: it supposes to install package with python installation. not sure what went wrong

Comment: In case it helps someone: In my case (november 2018) it was solved by adding "universe" to apt sources (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061488/865083)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install python3-testresources
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest installing pip by the [PyPA guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) on Ubuntu 18.04, since the pip version is too old if we install it by `sudo apt install python3-pip`.

The following work for me:

`# curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

`# python get-pip.py`

BTW, the default location of pip is `/usr/local/bin/pip`, in case can't find the PATH.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip python-dev
```

This will remove the pip and Python. Then install the required version of Python and pip.

Comment: I've installed it freshly. I'm asking the correct way to update pip3, not reinstall.