# Install pip Python

Tags: python

Please, why i have pip 1.5.4 in the (venv) ? how can i upgrade pip to 8.1.2 in the venv ? Thanks

```
 root@graphene-95:~# pip -V
 pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
 (python 2.7)
 root@graphene-95:~# pip3 -V
  The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by     
 typing:
 apt-get install python3-pip
 root@graphene-95:~# source ~/tensorflow/venv/bin/activate
 (venv)root@graphene-95:~# pip -V
 pip 1.5.4 from /root/tensorflow/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (python 2.7)
 (venv)root@graphene-95:~# pip3 -v
 The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by   
 typing:

 apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip` will upgrade pip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update pip itself from inside my virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment)

Comment: @ggdx   in the (venv) ?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: @user1543915 - Yes. If you're in the venv, you should only do things in the venv so you don't screw up your host environment (i.e. the whole point of using a virtual env in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install a specific version of pip , use the command
`pip install pip==8.2.1` after activating your virtual environment.

And , if you get SSL error like this

`Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping`.

Then , first you to have get the latest pip , then only you can install a particular version of pip.So, to get latest pip, execute this command

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`.

Now try this `pip install pip==8.2.1`

Comment: in the (venv)   https://www.dropbox.com/s/i435ikd7t0q4uy4/CaptureS.PNG?dl=0

Comment: this error is due to the proxy settings of your system.pip is trying to download the package via proxy and it fails to do so.

Answer (score 0):

i solved with the following command, and it worked for me:
`sudo su root`
`sudo su root apt-get purge -y python-pip`
`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py python ./get-pip.py`
`apt-get install python-pip`