# unable to upgrade pip version 10.0.1 to 18.0 in cmd

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to upgrade pip but the below command didn't worked out. Currently, I have pip version 10.0.1 and I want to upgrade it to 18.0

command I tried in cmd:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

It's showing:

> Attribute Error:module 're' has no attribute 'findall'

Comment: check your python version, you may have to run `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: I ran that command but still encountering same error .It's showing :
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment) Please have a look at this answer.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I fixed it...there were few issues with my directories and it was unable to locate the python file.

Answer (score 1):

There might be something wrong with your pip instalation

try this:

```
curl bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
```

Comment: Thanks...this solved my issue..been trying to work around it from some time.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is with my version of pip 9.0, upgrading always fails (I run a MacBook with OSX 10.7.5) showing similar message like this example , If any one had an idea...:

> $ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
>
> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
>   But every time I use pip install, is this:
>
> $ pip install lxml
>
> Collecting lxml
>
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lxml (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for lxml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have exited python and you are back in main Anaconda terminal. Press

```
exit
```

to leave python and then run this code

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

or run the commands below;

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge 
conda update pip
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in windows and using virtual env then use

```
(virtual env) c/path>easy_install -U pip
```

this will update pip inside the virtual env and if you do it outside of virtual env then it should also work there as well.

Answer (score -1):

> this will update pip 18.0 in virtual env and if you do it outside of virtual env then it should also work there as well.

python -m pip install --upgrade pip 18.0