# What versions of python, anaconda and tensorflow work best to gether on windows 8.1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

taking different machine learning courses. i tried to install tensorflow after deleting my old anaconda/python (which took a while) and downloading 3.7, but then ran into version problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment). downloading anaconda3 5.20 now.

so is there a preferred combination of recent python, anaconda, and tensorflow versions that play well together on windows 8.1.

edit: looks like anaconda can deal with [different versions](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python) of python.

edit2: trying:

```
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

gets tensorflow installed and working but issues a warning:

You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\ray>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3a
f41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
tensorflow 1.10.0 has requirement setuptools<=39.1.0, but you'll have setuptools
 40.0.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

so now i have a red warning.

Comment: Have you tried following the [official guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) that seems to suggest creating a python 3.5 environment?

Comment: i will try: conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5 when the install finishes. thanks

Comment: You can look here https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel to see different combinations of tensorflow and python versions. A link for most of the applicable version combinations can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622526/4575793

Comment: nice links. thanks.