# Python pip install pyarrow error, unable to execute 'cmake'

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, pip, amazon-emr, pyarrow

I'm trying to install the pyarrow on a master instance of my EMR cluster, however I'm always receiving this error.

```
[hadoop@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX ~]$ sudo /usr/bin/pip-3.4 install pyarrow
Collecting pyarrow
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/a0/f7e9dfd8988d94f4952f9b50eb04e14a80fbe39218520725aab53daab57c/pyarrow-0.10.0.tar.gz (2.1MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.2MB 643kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages (from pyarrow)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pyarrow)
Installing collected packages: pyarrow
Running setup.py install for pyarrow ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/mnt/tmp/pip-build-pr3y5_mu/pyarrow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-vmywdpeg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
warnings.warn(msg)
/mnt/tmp/pip-build-pr3y5_mu/pyarrow/.eggs/setuptools_scm-3.1.0-py3.4.egg/setuptools_scm/utils.py:118: UserWarning: 'git' was not found
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pyarrow
copying pyarrow/pandas_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pyarrow
copying pyarrow/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pyarrow
......
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pyarrow/tests/data
copying pyarrow/tests/data/v0.7.1.all-named-index.parquet -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pyarrow/tests/data
copying pyarrow/tests/data/v0.7.1.column-metadata-handling.parquet -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pyarrow/tests/data
copying pyarrow/tests/data/v0.7.1.parquet -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pyarrow/tests/data
copying pyarrow/tests/data/v0.7.1.some-named-index.parquet -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pyarrow/tests/data
running build_ext
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
-- Runnning cmake for pyarrow
cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.4  -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /mnt/tmp/pip-build-pr3y5_mu/pyarrow
unable to execute 'cmake': No such file or directory
error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/mnt/tmp/pip-build-pr3y5_mu/pyarrow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-vmywdpeg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /mnt/tmp/pip-build-pr3y5_mu/pyarrow/
```

I don't know why it says 'command 'cmake' failed with exit status 1', In fact to be sure, I preinstalled the cmake, but I still get this error. Furthermore, I can do sudo pip install pyarrow with no problem, but I'm getting error when using sudo pip-3.4 install pyarrow. Am I missing something or maybe this error has nothing to do with cmake? I'll appreciate for any help.

Comment: Is `cmake` on your `$PATH` ? Your use of `sudo` might reset `$PATH`. Check with `sudo env` (or don't use sudo to install simple modules)

Comment: @Botje cmake is in the $PATH. I'm permission denied if without sudo in EMR. The weird thing here is I can using sudo pip install pyarrow with no problem, but I got error when using sudo pip-3.4 install.

Comment: I was getting this error with `sudo pip-3.4 install pyarror`: `package 'arrow' not found`?  Installing version 0.9.0 did work for me but I wouldn't call that a ideal solution.  The AWS AMI doesn't seem to have a package for arrow.  I'm reluctant to download and build arrow myself.  Maybe I'll just use python2.

Comment: If anyone is looking for this in 2021, what worked for me was to set export `ARROW_HOME=/usr/local`, then `pip3 install pyarrow` worked flawlessly.

Comment: Same issue now with Python 3.12. Resolved by downgrading version to 3.10.7.

Answer (score 27):

For me (on linux) the problem was a too old version of pip

```sh
pip --version
> pip 18.1
```

which is according to [arrow.apache.org](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html) too low:

> On Linux, you will need pip >= 19.0 to detect the prebuilt binary
> packages.

to upgrade `pip` to the latest version, this worked for me:

```sh
pip install --upgrade pip
```

but it might be different for you, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-upgrade-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment) for other ways to upgrade `pip`.

Answer (score 16):

Finally I found a way to get around this situation by installing an earlier version of pyarrow. I was trying to install pyarrow-0.10.0 which failed. But if I'm installing the pyarrow-0.9.0, it works. So I think there might be some compatible issues between cmake and pyarrow-0.10.0.

Comment: how did you install pyarrow-0.9.0 version?

Comment: @Sherlock You can use pip install pyarrow==0.9.0 or whatever other versions you want to.

Comment: this was the solution for me too!

Comment: Didn't work for me. I still have the error `pyarrow" failed with error code 1`

Comment: for my case, dependencies needed for the airflow databricks provider, install local provider did not attempt to install the correct pyarrow version, to find out what i needed (match the remote container where airflow was installed in AKS, i did `pip freeze | grep pyarrow`

Comment: i had to use python 3.9.16(and hope compatibility works as the remote airflow container has python 3.7.15)  for my virtual environment to get rid of the dependency error in the end. in the beginning i was using 3.7.15

Answer (score 3):

(MacOS) I was installing pyarrow and snowflake-connector-python on python3.11 virtual environment the error message was:

> Python pip install pyarrow error, unable to execute 'cmake'

solved by using python3.9 environment like

```
python3.9 -m venv myvenv
```

Comment: 3.10 also works

Answer (score 1):

Using the `--no-use-pep517` switch with pip did the trick for me.
(with Debian 11, Python 3.11, pip 22.3.1)

According to my understanding, pip tries going with [PEP-517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/) and build pyarrow from source.

When I tried, initially this failed with cmake. Once I've installed that via `apt-get install cmake`, I've got another error about Arrow is not being installed. Then I found out about `--no-use-pep517` from some GitHub issues:

Some tickets mentioning this workaround:

- https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/382#issuecomment-681085773
- https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/pull/355
- https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/8386#issuecomment-754763790

Answer (score 0):

On MAC with the current setup:

```
  Python: 3.8.12
  platform: macOS-13.6.3-x86_64-i386-64bit
  macos: 13.6.3
  machine: x86_64
  bits: 64
  pip: n/a
  setuptools: 69.0.3
  scikit-build: 0.17.6
  PEP517_BUILD_BACKEND=setuptools.build_meta
```

The solution was:

1. Upgrade PIP: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
2. Upgrade cmake: pip3 install cmake

Answer (score -3):

Seems there is problem with pyarrow with cmake and pip.

You can use conda instead of pip.

conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow