# How to upgrade pip?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I want to install tensorflow, but I need to upgrade pip. How to upgrade pip?  I tried to upgrade through the command line and this is what I got.

```
C:\Users\garoo>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-10.0.1.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\garoo>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: use `sudo` or `--user` for installation

Comment: This is purely information. You do not **need** to upgrade `pip`.

Comment: if you *do* want to update pip, open Windows ® `CMD.EXE` in administrator mode and give the command it gave you `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Please avoid screenshotting what is better conveyed via copy/paste.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update\upgrade pip itself from inside my virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-upgrade-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment)

Answer (score 38):

To upgrade pip from the command line:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: This might destroy portability of python distributions like WinPython because pip stores an absolute path to python.exe during this installion step. If someone knows a way to keep portability, please let me know.

Answer (score 11):

You do not need to upgrade pip to install tensorflow. Although if you still wish to do so you can try this

```
pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

Else try running the CMD as Admin

Answer (score 2):

How to upgrade pip using command prompt:

1. Open the command prompt from the Start Menu

   - Click the lower-left Start button to open the Start Menu
   - input `cmd` in the empty box and tap Command Prompt in the results
2. Use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to uninstall the old `pip` package and install the current version.

```
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 284.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-22.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.0.3
Successfully installed pip-22.0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

For permission error while installing Python dependencies, you need to run the terminal or command prompt or powershell  as `administrator`

Example below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might help someone:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['pip','install','--upgrade','pip'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding up to @Iain Hunter's answer, if the command prompt provides you with an error:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

Try changing `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to `py -m pip install --upgrade pip`. If `cmd` still provides you the error, try downloading Python once again; Maybe you accidentally unchecked the download `pip` box while downloading Python.

Answer (score -6):

```
m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Write this clause on terminal and press Enter
m pip install --upgrade pip