# How to update pip to latest version 20.0.2

Tags: python

While using this command

```
"python -m pip install --upgrade pip"
```

I get this error message:

```
"Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-19.2.3.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."
```

What's the solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update\upgrade pip itself from inside my virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-upgrade-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too sure what the error could be, but I suspect the problem is that you are not running your terminal/command prompt as an *administrator*. So when you are launching your terminal/command prompt just right-click and `run as administrator`

Or you could try using a different method of updating `pip`,

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: This was not helpful

Answer (score 4):

Can you try with this command instead ? Also if any issue persists try running `cmd` as **Administrator**

```
python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```