# Upgrading pip in my venv is throwing error

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I have python==3.8.5 installed on my Window 10. I created a venv with the command

> python -m venv venv

When I try to upgrade pip using

> (venv)...> pip install --upgrade pip

It throws an error

> \venv\Scripts\pip.exe_*main*_.py", line 4, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

I also tried

> (venv)...> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

As suggested in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223296)

I think the problem is with my venv but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: try pip3 for python 3

Comment: It's windows not linux

Comment: i also use window and pip3 does work.

Comment: Okay, let me check